# Best strategy to persist configuration variables of a JSP web aplication?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jersey

I'm implementing a web application using Java (jsp). Now I'm adding some configuration buttons into the application, and I need to know which is the best strategy to persist them.

For example, I need to add a switch which will tell if each 10 jobs with errors the main worker must be stopped. It is a boolean variable called "safeStop". For that I need to persist if that config value is activated. This persistent value must be there even if the server is reset so it is not enough to persist it on RAM, it mus be persisted on disk.

This application will process thousands of works at day, so I need a safe and efficient way of persisting configuration.

I can't find any coherent info about different strategies of doing this and which is the best option.

Comment: Hm, I cannot believe that you don't have any idea how to persist some configuration values. You say the options should be persisted to disk. Then write a file in custom format or write a properties file or write it to a database. "Best strategy" depends on your needs and is primarily opinion-based. If you already use a database then why not use it for the options, too?

Comment: instead of telling that you can't believe me, why not to propose your best approach in an answer?

Comment: Because you are the only one who is able to decide what's best for your project. I don't know your requirements and general conditions. You have several alternatives, now it is up to you to balance pros and cons.

Comment: Has someone hacked your account NPE?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice would be to keep all the conf variables in a database and set a cookie on client side if that data needs to be processed. Once operations are performed update the values on server on session end or after a certain time or data volume or at the end when all processing operations are complete.  This way you'll achieve performance, store information on something besides ram while using the RAM for shorter transaction operations