# Calling two different urls when Switch button is On or Off

Tags: css, html

I know how to call a url when a user press a button. This is a sample:

```
<form action="generator/doWork" method="GET" target="_blank">
     <input type="submit" value="Do Work">
</form>
```

The problem is that now, the objective is to enable or disable one of the functionalities of my web when the user press the switch. When the switch is ON, `generator/disable` url must be called when the switch is pressed and OFF is setted, and when the switch is OFF, `generator/enable` url must be called when the switch gets pressed and ON must be setted. How can I do that?

This is my switch button.

```
<div class="value" id="onOffSwitch">
<div class="onoffswitch">
     <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
     </label>
</div>
</div>
```

css of the switch button:

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #D40066;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #D40066;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(52px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(52px);
  transform: translateX(52px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript you could do the following:

```js
(function(){ //wait for load event
  var form = document.getElementById('formtoedit');
  var button = document.getElementById('button_switch');

  button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(this.checked){
      form.setAttribute('action','generator/stop');
    }else{
      form.setAttribute('action','generator/doWork');        
    }
  });
 
})();
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #D40066;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #D40066;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(52px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(52px);
  transform: translateX(52px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formtoedit" action="generator/doWork" method="GET" target="_blank">
     <input type="submit" value="Do Work">
</form>

<div class="value" id="onOffSwitch">
<div class="onoffswitch">
     <label class="switch">
        <input id="button_switch" type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
     </label>
</div>
</div>
```

This changes `action` attribute of form based on button state.

Comment: Please, could be possible to do this simple thing without using jQuery? thank you

Comment: @NullPointerException transferd to pure js

Comment: If you meant do do this without any javascript, it's not plausible. This is as native as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this objective by simple jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.switch').click(function(){
    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')) {
      // When ON
      $('form').prop('action', 'generator/enable');
    } else {
      // When OFF
      $('form').prop('action', 'generator/disable');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #D40066;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #D40066;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(52px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(52px);
  transform: translateX(52px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="generator/disable" method="GET" target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" value="Do Work">
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="value" id="onOffSwitch">
<div class="onoffswitch">
     <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="slider round"></div>
     </label>
</div>
</div>
```

Please run the code snippet and see changing of the `action` of the form via inspect element in chrome ... Let me know :)

Comment: Hi, thank you, but it is possible to achieve this simple functionality without using jQuery?

Comment: @NullPointerException No sorry... Because you wanted it to change dynamically on user end so jQuery is what you want right here.

Comment: thanks. It is possible to persist that value of that switch on my server?

Comment: Yes it is possible :)

Comment: And it is easy? Did you have any idea about how to achieve it? It is a jsp application, I openned this question but no one is answering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881554/best-strategy-to-persist-configuration-variables-of-a-jsp-web-aplication

Comment: Well I don't work with JSP but I know a guy and forwarded your question link to him. He might help you :)